# How to find the version of crystal reports running on my system?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, version

Is there any built-in function in C# to get the version of installed crystal reports in my computer?

Comment: Check installed applications. You will see the version of CR redist package there.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function.
But you can check each [assembly version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225607(v=vs.80).aspx):

```
try
{
    var cr13_installed = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(
        "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    );
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
{
    // not installed
}
```